# Choosing column in where condition dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I am new to dynamic SQL programming. There are a set of tables with different schema (rows and values) whose record count is being taken dynamically through a loop. However, the records which are soft deleted shouldn't be a part of record count. Each of the table has a column which signifies a soft delete in Table_Name_IS_DELETED, for instance TB1_IS_DELETED. Please help me in dynamically updating the column name in the where condition.

The code I have written for counts

```
SET @Query = 'SELECT @K  = COUNT(*) FROM ['+@DB_Source+'].['+@Table_Schema+'].['+@Table_Name+'] x WITH (NOLOCK)

    EXEC sp_executesql @Query, N'@K INT OUTPUT', @K=@K OUTPUT;
```

Now there should be a **WHERE** condition in the dynamic query which should be like "TB1_IS_DELETED = 1" and the table name (TB1) should be updated accordingly.

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Why do that? Why not just execute the appropriate SQL query? You gain nothing by concatenating strings like that. Even if you put that in a stored procedure you gain no performance or security benefits

Comment: BTW `NOLOCK` means "read dirty data while taking excessive locks and returning duplicate rows". It's not a `go-fast` switch. If you have a performance problem you need to find it and fix it, not try to cover it up

Comment: In this case I suspect the fields in the `WHERE` clause aren't covered by any index so the query has to scan everything. Using NOLOCK won't change that. Index the columns and make sure you include the `IsDeleted` field in the indexes. Or use a filtered index to only index rows that *don't* have `IsDeleted = 1`

Comment: Why do you have to have Table_Name_IsDeleted when you already have the table name?  It'd be far easier to say Table_Name.IsDeleted,.  If i you're only referring to one table in your query, just leave it as IsDeleted.

Comment: Careful, this isn't safe against injection. `...'[' + @param + @']...'` can easily be escaped. Example, `SET @DB_Source = N'master].sys.tables; CREATE LOGIN L WITH PASSWORD = '1', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;--';` Use `QUOTENAME` to **properly** quote your dynamic objects.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SET @Query = '
SELECT @K = COUNT(*) 
FROM '+quotename(@DB_Source)+'.'+quotename(@Table_Schema)+'.'+quotename(@Table_Name)+' x WITH (NOLOCK)
where '+quotename(@Column_Name)+'=1
' 

EXEC sp_executesql @Query, N'@K INT OUTPUT', @K=@K OUTPUT;
```